# Where to find the paper "Complex Powers of an Elliptic Operator (R. T. Seeley)"?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for a paper which could be useful in wrinting my Ph.D. thesis. The paper is:

> Complex powers of an elliptic operator (R. T. Seeley)

It's a bit old and I've already searched a lot in the internet and could not find it. So can anyone help me finding it?

**Obs.** I've already tried emailing people and still couldn't get it, so here is my last chance (and I guess this site is the best place to reach a great number of mathematicians so please don't close this question).

Comment: There are at least 3 pages that could be of use to you on the first page of Google's search results...

Comment: Check out Sci-Hub.

Answer (score 2):

Copies of “Complex Powers of an Elliptic Operator", R. T. Seeley, from Singular Integrals, 1967 (A. Calderon) and "Complex powers of elliptic pseudodifferential operators", Elmar Schrohe, Integral Equations and Operator Theory, 1986 have been distributed.

Comment: Sure, thanks =)

Comment: Done!! Thanks a lot man =)

Comment: Nice, could you share it too?

Comment: Finished!! Thanks again ^.^